# Break at Win32-API to inspect process's behaviors

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols

I am debugging 'smartgit for windows'.
I want to know how it invokes 'git' (command it pass to git). I start VS and attach the process of smartgit.

I suspect it communicates with git by windows pipe, and other APIs like `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` and so on, so set breakpoints at those functions.

After some Options be set, I tick off 'Just My Code' and delete all exclude modules In symbol settings then I download symbols. and I can ensure that 'Kernel32.pdb' was loaded.

`'smartgit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Q:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\bin\smartgit.exe'. Module was built without symbols.
'smartgit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'smartgit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'smartgit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'smartgit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.`

`_ReadFile@20:
765EF0C0 8B FF                mov         edi,edi

765EF0C2 55                   push        ebp

765EF0C3 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp

765EF0C5 6A FE                push        0FFFFFFFEh

765EF0C7 68 C0 52 68 76       push        766852C0h`

but still I got the disasm code view when bps were triggered. I am quiet sure that I have ticked 'Show Source Code' option.

WHY? and how to view C code of `ReadFile`, I want to know what it(smartgit) reads and writes. So I inspect through `lpBuffer`.

Comment: It is not always very obvious what two-by-four is needed.  Describe in your own words what you think "Module was built without symbols" might mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdb` files not containing source code. it can containing information how map `RVA` address to source file/line. but this information is useful only if you have this source files. because you have no source files for windows system dlls (ntdll, kernel32, kernelbase..) you and can not view it c/c++ code in debugger. and usual information about source files/lines is stripped from system pdbs - because source files anyway not exist for download. but with pdb files you can view internal functions and symbols names (not only exported symbols) - already great advantage which very help in debugging.

in case `ReadFile` - for what you need source code here ? when you can view say `lpBuffer` address in `[esp + 8]` at first instruction (`765EF0C0` in your dump) and then in `[ebp+0xc]` ?

Comment: @TanakaYasen - but you have not source files for ntdll, kernel32, kernelbase. and can not view it c/c++ code. however ReadFile function very small and simply here not need source

Comment: thx, you remind me of that when source code changes, breakpoints will become invalid because the mapping from `RVA` to source code is incorrect. I know [esp + offset] is on behalf of the params and [eip] below `call` instruction, because calling a function is always compiled as the asm sequence that `push param3; push param2; push param1 call _func`. but it's confusing that the offset differs from calling convention(stdcall/cdecl).I am not quiet familiar with that affair. Even if be familiar, also an inefficient job. where to download source code of `Kernel32.c`(compatible with Kernel32.pdb)?

Comment: @TanakaYasen - `where to download source code of Kernel32.c` - afraid that this is not possible )

Comment: Thank you all the same. I find a non-official implementation `kernel32.c` (wine on Linux), mustn't compatible with pdb.  :) I hook the api `static HANDLE WINAPI myCreateProcess(...){
 HANDLE t = oldCreateProcess(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes, bInheritHandles, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, lpCurrentDirectory, lpStartupInfo, lpProcessInformation);//set breakpoint here
 return t;
}`with a light-weighted lib called `Minhook`(like MS's detour) and it's resolved.